# How to display orders from a specific month and year in SQL (Oracle SqlDeveloper)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display the orders that were in February of 2012.

The date is a DATE data type and I can only figure out how to get it to display it by putting in the full date like 08-FEB-2012.

This is a very small database and is a beginner class. We just started last week.

What I have is:

```
SELECT cust_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = '08-FEB-2012'
```

There are three orders from February, and I need to display all three of those.

Thanks

Comment: Are you basically asking how to retrieve rows with an order date between a range of dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to compare the year and month to your desired period:

```
SELECT cust_id
FROM orders
WHERE TO_CHAR(order_date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2012-02'
```

In general, though, this precludes the use of indexes.  So, it is better to use comparisons with no functions, if performance is at all an issue:

```
SELECT cust_id
FROM orders
WHERE order_date >= DATE '2012-02-01' AND
      order_date < DATE '2012-03-01';
```

Notice that this does *not* use `between`.  In the event that the order date has a time component, the above will work.  Using `between` often means that you will miss times on the last day of the month.  In other words, this version works regardless of whether or not `order_date` has a time component.

Comment: I ended up using LIKE '%FEB%'; Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from orders
where order_date between to_date('02/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') 
      and to_date('02/29/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

FYI, never assume the default date format. It could vary from system to system. Always specify it.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the date format because I displayed all of the dates. But your tip is on point. Thanks!